# Unable to serve Django static files on AWS elastic-beanstalk

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have searched many questions and answers, AWS and Django(2.0) docs but still unable to serve static files. I am new to AWS and have made just basic web app.

My settings.py have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ..
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ..
]  

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My project directory:

```
|.ebextensions
|--django.config
|.elasticbeanstalk
|--config.yml
|app
|--migrations
|--static
|--tempates
|--admin.py
|--......
|--views.py
|project
|--settings.py
|--urls.py
|--wsgi.py
|static
|manage.py
|requirements
```

My django.config has:

```
container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: awtest/wsgi.py
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

HTML source :

```
<html>
  <head

<title>Home</title>

  </head>
  <body>

      <img src="/static/app/symbol-logo.png" alt="" style="width:50px;height:60px;"">

<h1>AWS</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I run this on my computer it works fine, i can see the image but as soon as I deploy on AWS beanstalk I am unable to  see the image and when I check source and click on image url, it says `Forbidden, you don't have permission to access the image on server`.

Can anyone point where I might be going wrong?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a `static` map in your `app` folder and a `static` map in your root dir? The current `static` dir that is called right now is the directory in the root dir.

Comment: It is because my app has its own static folder and when I use `collect-static `it creates another one in root directory as i have given ` STATIC_ROOT` as base dir.

Comment: Why don't you combine the static directories?

Comment: try opening the image using absolute image url,  the image might not be having public access

Comment: That what's `collect-static` does, in future i will have more app each having different static folder

Comment: @AsitRout can try to do that but then it would be just a temporary hack and would not be solving the bigger problem

Comment: Try to change the document root. Go to EBS console>Application>configuration>Software configuration and change the "Document root" under "container options".

Comment: @ssk I already have `/static/ = /static/` assigned there

Comment: Have you tried to update the default configurations in the configuration pages of elastic-beanstalk? As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115553/7707749

Comment: @KingReload, yes i have tried it

Comment: Optionally you could just run collectstatic locally and commit the files to git. Then when you run 'eb deploy', even if that command fails, the app should serve up the static files properly.

Comment: @ssk Have used collectstatic and then eb deploy still no use and have also specified collectstatic in container commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deployed this in different instance in AWS wih different configurations and it worked.

From django.config I removed

```
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

In settings.py file I made `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'`

and in configuration settings in Elastic-beanstalk console I changed

```
/static/ = /static/
```

to

```
/static/ = static/
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of EBS the namespace changed to `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles`, like this:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```